# Why does this .c file #include itself?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Why does this `.c` file `#include` itself?

- https://github.com/powturbo/TurboPFor-Integer-Compression

**vsimple.c**

```
#define USIZE 8
#include "vsimple.c"
#undef USIZE

#define USIZE 16
#include "vsimple.c"
#undef USIZE

#define USIZE 32
#include "vsimple.c"
#undef USIZE

#define USIZE 64
#include "vsimple.c"
#undef USIZE
```

Comment: Doing this breaks some indexing systems used on Eclipse.  I don't recommend it.

Comment: this USIZE macro is used in another macro TEMPLATE2(function, USIZE), to create functions to 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits, but I can't find where this replications occurs.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There are indications that the mechanism in question is not represented by the shown code. The `#ifndef`s are important and how USIZE is used is important.

Comment: In this version, it's including a separate template .h file, which is a more appropriate use of the pre-processor: https://github.com/matthieu-m/TurboPFor/blob/master/vsimple.c

Comment: @stark On the other hand, I wouldn't recommend using eclipse for C development, anyway. And breaking on this is just one more reason to avoid it.

Comment: @Stark if it's valid C then Eclipse clearly needs fixing.

Comment: One way to see how this works is to preprocess the file and look at the final output.  Like `gcc -E foo.c`.  That will verify that it isn't infinitely recursive, e.g. that these includes are inside an `#ifdef` which you omitted.  The contents of the output should hint you in the direction of what's going on and what the point is.

Comment: See also the ["X-macro"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/02/01/x-macros/) technique.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The file includes itself so the same source code can be used to generate 4 different sets of functions for specific values of the macro `USIZE`.

The `#include` directives are actually enclosed in an `#ifndef`, which limits the recursion to a single level:

```
#ifndef USIZE

// common definitions
...
//

#define VSENC vsenc
#define VSDEC vsdec

#define USIZE 8
#include "vsimple.c"
#undef USIZE

#define USIZE 16
#include "vsimple.c"
#undef USIZE

#define USIZE 32
#include "vsimple.c"
#undef USIZE

#define USIZE 64
#include "vsimple.c"
#undef USIZE

#else // defined(USIZE)

// macro expanded size specific functions using token pasting

...

#define uint_t TEMPLATE3(uint, USIZE, _t)

unsigned char *TEMPLATE2(VSENC, USIZE)(uint_t *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned char *__restrict out) {
   ...
}

unsigned char *TEMPLATE2(VSDEC, USIZE)(unsigned char *__restrict ip, size_t n, uint_t *__restrict op) {
   ...
}

#endif
```

The functions defined in this module are

```
// vsencNN: compress array with n unsigned (NN bits in[n]) values to the buffer out. Return value = end of compressed output buffer out
unsigned char *vsenc8( unsigned char  *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned char  *__restrict out);
unsigned char *vsenc16(unsigned short *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned char  *__restrict out);
unsigned char *vsenc32(unsigned       *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned char  *__restrict out);
unsigned char *vsenc64(uint64_t       *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned char  *__restrict out);

// vsdecNN: decompress buffer into an array of n unsigned values. Return value = end of compressed input buffer in
unsigned char *vsdec8( unsigned char  *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned char  *__restrict out);
unsigned char *vsdec16(unsigned char  *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned short *__restrict out);
unsigned char *vsdec32(unsigned char  *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned       *__restrict out);
unsigned char *vsdec64(unsigned char  *__restrict in, size_t n, uint64_t       *__restrict out);
```

They are all expanded from the two function definitions in **vsimple.c**:

```
unsigned char *TEMPLATE2(VSENC, USIZE)(uint_t *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned char *__restrict out) {
   ...
}

unsigned char *TEMPLATE2(VSDEC, USIZE)(unsigned char *__restrict ip, size_t n, uint_t *__restrict op) {
   ...
}
```

The `TEMPLATE2` and `TEMPLATE3` macros are defined in [conf.h](https://github.com/powturbo/TurboPFor-Integer-Compression/blob/master/conf.h) as

```
#define TEMPLATE2_(_x_, _y_) _x_##_y_
#define TEMPLATE2(_x_, _y_) TEMPLATE2_(_x_,_y_)

#define TEMPLATE3_(_x_,_y_,_z_) _x_##_y_##_z_
#define TEMPLATE3(_x_,_y_,_z_) TEMPLATE3_(_x_, _y_, _z_)
```

These macros are classic preprocessor constructions to create identifiers via token pasting. `TEMPLATE2` and `TEMPLATE2_` are more commonly called `GLUE` and `XGLUE`.

The function template starts as:

```
unsigned char *TEMPLATE2(VSENC, USIZE)(uint_t *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned char *__restrict out) ...
```

It is expanded in the first recursive inclusion with `USIZE` defined as `8` into:

```
unsigned char *vsenc8(uint8_t *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned char *__restrict out) ...
```

The second recursive inclusion, with `USIZE` defined as `16`, expands the template as:

```
unsigned char *vsenc16(uint16_t *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned char *__restrict out) ...
```

and 2 more inclusions define `vsenc32` and `vsenc64`.

This usage of preprocessed source code is more common with separate files: one for the instantiating part that has all the common definitions, especially the macros, and a separate file for the code and data templates, which is included multiple times with different macro definitions.

A good example is the generation of enums, string and structures arrays from [atom](https://github.com/bellard/quickjs/blob/master/quickjs-atom.h) and [opcode](https://github.com/bellard/quickjs/blob/master/quickjs-opcode.h) definitions in QuickJS.

Comment: I don't understand the mechanism on which one definition of: unsigned char *TEMPLATE2(VSENC, USIZE)(uint_t *__restrict in, size_t n, unsigned char *__restrict out) {...}, the compiler replicate on the 4 options of USIZE

Comment: @RodrigoBelli: I updated the answer with more details about the function templating used in this package.

Comment: Assuming this isn't compiler-ignored UB, then this technique can be used to create unbounded recursion, which is the missing piece when most people analyze the C preprocessor as Turing-incomplete.

Comment: @JacobManaker: Interesting approach... But this unbounded recursion is severely limited without invoking undefined behavior as the C Standard does document in **5.2.4.1 Translations limits** *The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits:* [...] *- 15 nesting levels for `#included` files*.

Comment: This technique is [occasionally called ‘X-macros’](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/02/01/x-macros/), though personally I find the name awful.

Comment: @Jacop Manaker "Turing Complete" is often used loosely. Any implementation of the preprocessor is Turing-incomplete if infinite recursion requires infinite memory. Since all current practical implementations of the prepocessor implement finite recursion in finite memory, none are definitially Turing-complete. If you think this is important or not is a personal opinion.

Answer (score 41):

The accepted answer by @chqrlie 100% explains what is happening. This is just a complementary commentary.

If using C++ we could define two template functions to provide all the implementations of `vsenc8`, `vsenc16`, `vsenc32`, `vsenc64` and `vsdec8`, `vsdec16`, `vsdec32`, `vsdec64`. In contrast, however, C is a very simple language and does not support templates. A common trick to have the same power (in uglier packaging) is to use the dumb macro facility of the language and let the C preprocessor do the equivalent job for us. Most C programmers of some experience will encounter and use this kind of construct repeatedly during their careers.

What makes this particular example a bit tedious to understand is that the implementation file is unconventionally parsed 5 times to first have some preparatory definitions and then the four variants of the two functions. The first pass (inside `#ifndef USIZE` preprocessor block) will have the needed macros and non-variant stuff defined and will recursively `#include` itself four times with different `USIZE` values (`8`, `16`, `32`, `64`) as template values. When recursively included, the corresponding `#else` preprocessor block is parsed with the result of two functions generated according to the value of `USIZE` macro constant used for the pass.

More conventional, conceptually clearer, and instantly understandable way would be to include the template functions from a different files, say `vsimple.impl`:

```
#define USIZE 8
/* Generate vsenc8(), vsdec8()... */ 
#include "vsimple.impl"

#undef USIZE
#define USIZE 16
/* Generate vsenc16(), vsdec16()... */ 
#include "vsimple.impl"

#undef USIZE
#define USIZE 32
/* Generate vsenc32(), vsdec32()... */ 
#include "vsimple.impl"

#undef USIZE
#define USIZE 64
/* Generate vsenc64(), vsdec64()... */ 
#include "vsimple.impl"
```

The including file `vsimple.c` and the included file `vsimple.impl` could then also be organized to be much clearer in what they define and when. Most C programmers would recognize the implementational pattern and immediately know what is happening.

Recursively and repeatedly including itself this way invokes a feel of hocus-pocery which would attract applauds for an obfuscated C competition entry but not for mission critical production code.

Comment: Good suggestion. Incidentally, `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` and `"vint.h"` are included in the wrong part of the `#ifdef` file, not a problem thanks to include guards, but sloppy nonetheless.

Comment: @chqrlie: I just basically elaborated and opinionated the point you already made in your answer, "This usage of preprocessed source code is more common with separate files..." ;-)

Comment: My assumption is that the purpose of doing it this way is not for obfuscation, rather it is to reduce the number of files that need to be managed if copying this code into some other project.

Comment: @MosheKatz I am not saying the original purpose was obfuscation. I only wanted to convey that recursively #including oneself could be a useful addition in the basket of tricks when grafting an entry in The International C Programming Contest (https://www.ioccc.org/). Avoiding addition of a file to a list of thirty or something files hardly counts as worthy of the cost of code readability in my mind.

Answer (score 3):

It is recursion. Recursion is useful here because C preprocessing doesn't have looping. Moreover, it's desirable to perpetrate a trick using one file rather than proliferating multiple files.

Suppose you were required to write a function which interpolates the integers from 1 to 5 into a template string, and prints that on standard output. Suppose you were required to write exactly one function and were prohibited from loops, or copy-pasted `printf` statements. You might do this:

```
void template_print(const char *fmt, int n)
{
   if (n == 0) {
     template_print(fmt, 1);
     template_print(fmt, 2);
     template_print(fmt, 3);
     template_print(fmt, 4);
     template_print(fmt, 5);
   } else {
     /* imagine there are 30 lines of statements here we don't want
        to repeat five times. */
     printf(fmt, n);
   }
}
```

The top-level call to this is then `template_print("whatever %d\n", 0)` distinguished by the zero argument of the `n` parameter.

The top-level call with 0 is like the initial processing of `vsimple.c` without `USIZE` being defined.

The requirement for one function is analogous to being required to produce a single, self-contained `.c` file rather than an "interface" file which `#include`s an implementation.